# Unable to read Shared preference of my another app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider

I have two applications  -App 1 and App 2
I want to access App2 data from App1.
However, I don’t want a complex database structure, I just need to read couple of boolean flags from App1.
One way is to use content provider, where I will need to define table or some structured data.
Intent will be also not very useful as I don't want to launch app instantly after affecting any changes
 Any other relatively less complex workaround?
**(I don't want it to bind it to any adaptor or anything. Assume two boolean value in SharedPreference : Value1 & Value2 in App2 and I wish to access it via App1)**

Comment: You can use Android AIDL. in this way one application can serve data to the second one. take a look at [this link](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-aidl-937daf89e685). it seems a bit complicated at first glance, but it does exactly what you need

Comment: @Alish thanks for prompt reply. Please let me know if aidl approach is safe to use security wise.

Comment: as much as i know, you can restrict your service to requests from specified package name. but i do not know how much secure is this.

Answer (score 0):

**first app:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("test_prefs",
                Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("pref_key", true);
        editor.commit();
```

**second app:**

```
/* where com.example is the first app containing the preferences */
Context myContext = createPackageContext("com.example",Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY); 

SharedPreferences testPrefs = myContext.getSharedPreferences 
    ("test_prefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE); 


 boolean data = pref.getBoolean("pref_key", false);
```

Comment: Thanks Neeraj, is this safe to use security wise?

Comment: also Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE is shown as deprecated

Comment: you can use Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY

Comment: it crashes saying no longer available

Answer (score 0):

Right way to do it is to create a service on App1 and bind to this service from App2.

Here is a link for you reference. 
https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/components/bound-services.html